# Why aren't all my index values being displayed in this indexed table View?

Tags: xcode4.2

I have what appears to be a very odd table view in my app of some 40 almost identical table views. One of them will not display all the index values, no matter what I put in there it always drops at least one value, i.e. the last one in the last, no matter how many are there.[e.g. with only value "A", it will display "A", with "A" and "B", only "A" gets displayed, with "A", "B" and "C", it only displays "A" and "B". In debug mode Xcode says the array has the relevant number of objects, but even so they aren't displayed !!  Have you seen this before ??

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:

                             @"A",
                             @"B",
                             @"C",
                             @"D",
                             @"E",
                             @"G",
                             @"H",
                             @"I",
                             @"J",
                             @"K",
                             @"L",
                             @"M",
                             @"N",
                             @"O",
                             @"P",
                             @"S",
                             nil];

return tempArray;
}
```

Comment: You have to provide more code if you want some help

Comment: Is there a setting that would limit the number of index entries ?

Comment: No. There is probably an error in your UITableView delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

The window view dimensions were not correctly lined up in the storyboard - a simple explanation after all! :-)